# Add a react-bootstrap alert to handleSubmit in Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, formik

I'm trying to add a react-bootstrap alert to my Formik form so that the handleSubmit includes an alert to the user that the form has submitted.

I have used the react-bootstrap documented form of Alert, however I had to change the last line because that seems not to work (the error says that I haven't exported anything if I use the react-bootstrap documented form of alert.

My alert is:

```
import React from 'react';

import {
    Alert,
    Button,

  } from "react-bootstrap";

class AlertDismissible extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = { show: true };
    }

    render() {
      const handleHide = () => this.setState({ show: false });
      const handleShow = () => this.setState({ show: true });
      return (
        <>
          <Alert show={this.state.show} variant="light">
            <Alert.Heading>Thanks for your interest </Alert.Heading>
            <p>
              We'll be in touch with login details shortly.
            </p>
            <hr />
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-end">
              <Button onClick={handleHide} variant="outline-success">
                Close
              </Button>
            </div>
          </Alert>

          {!this.state.show && <Button onClick={handleShow}>Show Alert</Button>}
        </>
      );
    }
  }


export default AlertDismissible;
```

The documentation shows a final line as:

```
render(<AlertDismissible />);
```

If I try to use that, an error message saying that render is not defined, and that nothing has been exported appears. So - I replaced that line with my final line.

Then, in my form I have:

```
handleSubmit = (formState, { resetForm }) => {
        // Now, you're getting form state here!
        const payload = {
            ...formState,
            role: formState.role.value,
            createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
          }
          console.log("formvalues", payload);

        fsDB
          .collection("register")
          .add(payload)
          .then(docRef => {
            resetForm(initialValues);

          })
          .then => {<AlertDismissible />}

          .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
          });
    }
```

I don't actually know how to get the alert to work (the then statement above is a guess - I can't find any examples. This guess gives an error that says:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"
```

I've tried adding ";" in every place I can think to put one, but it keeps generating errors.

If I try it like this:

```
.then(<AlertDismissible />)
```

I get no errors and the form submits, but the alert is not displayed.

Does anyone know how to call a react-bootstrap alert in the handle submit function?

Submit button has:

```
<Button
  variant="outline-primary"
  type="submit"
  style={style3}
  id="submitRegistration"
  onClick={handleSubmit}
  disabled={!dirty || isSubmitting}>
   Register
</Button>
```

The onSubmit has:

```
onSubmit={
  this.handleSubmit
}
```

**My entire form looks like this:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage, withFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import Select from "react-select";
import { fsDB, firebase, settings } from "../../firebase";
import Temporarynav from '../navigation/Temporarynav.jsx';
import Demo from '../landing/Demo.jsx';
import Footer from '../footer/Footer.jsx';
import "./preregister/Form.css";
import AlertDismissible from '../auth/preregister/Alert';


import {
    Badge,
    Button,
    Col,
    ComponentClass,
    Feedback,
    FormControl,
    FormGroup,
    Table,
    Row,
    Container
  } from "react-bootstrap";
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert';

  const style1 = {
    width: "60%",
    margin: "auto"
  };

  const style2 = {
    paddingTop: "2em"
  };

  const style3 = {
    marginRight: "2em"
  };



const initialValues = {
firstName: "",
lastName: "",
email: "",
role: "",
consent: false,
createdAt: ''
}


class PreregForm extends React.Component {

    // constructor(props) {
    //   super(props);

    //   // the flag isFormDone will control where you will show the Alert component
    //   this.state = {
    //     isFormDone: false
    //   };
    // }
    handleSubmit = (formState, { resetForm }) => {
        // Now, you're getting form state here!
        const payload = {
            ...formState,
            role: formState.role.value,
            createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
          }
          console.log("formvalues", payload);

        fsDB
          .collection("preregistrations")
          .add(payload)
          .then(docRef => {
            resetForm(initialValues);

          })
          .then(() => {
            // Here is where you flag your form completion and allow the alert to be shown.
            // this.setState((prevState) => {...prevState, isFormDone: true});
          .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
          });
    }

    render() {
        const options = [
            { value: "academic", label: "Academic Researcher" },
            { value: "student", label: "Student (inc PhD)" },
        ] 

        // const {isFormDone} = this.state;

        return(
            <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
                    firstName: Yup.string().required("First Name is required"),
                    lastName: Yup.string().required("Last Name is required"),
                    email: Yup.string()
                        .email("Email is invalid")
                        .required("Email is required"),
                    role: Yup.string().nullable().required(
                        "It will help us get started if we know a little about your background"
                    ),
                    consent: Yup.boolean().oneOf(
                        [true],
                        "You must accept the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy"
                    )
                })}  
                onSubmit={
                  this.handleSubmit
                }
                render={({ 
                    errors, 
                    status, 
                    touched, 
                    setFieldValue,
                    setFieldTouched, 
                    handleSubmit, 
                    isSubmitting, 
                    dirty, 
                    values 
                }) => {

                  return (
                    <div>  
                    <Temporarynav />  
                    <Form style={style1}>
                      <h1 style={style2}>Get Started</h1>
                      <p>
                        We're almost ready to open this up to the research community. By
                        registering now, you'll be first in line when the doors open.
                      </p>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                        <Field
                          name="firstName"
                          type="text"
                          className={
                            "form-control" +
                            (errors.firstName && touched.firstName ? " is-invalid" : "")
                          }
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage
                          name="firstName"
                          component="div"
                          className="invalid-feedback"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                        <Field
                          name="lastName"
                          type="text"
                          className={
                            "form-control" +
                            (errors.lastName && touched.lastName ? " is-invalid" : "")
                          }
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage
                          name="lastName"
                          component="div"
                          className="invalid-feedback"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                        <Field
                          name="email"
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="Please use your work email address"
                          className={
                            "form-control" +
                            (errors.email && touched.email ? " is-invalid" : "")
                          }
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage
                          name="email"
                          component="div"
                          className="invalid-feedback"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="role">
                        Which role best describes yours?
                        </label>

                        <Select
                        key={`my_unique_select_keyrole`}
                        name="role"
                        className={
                            "react-select-container" +
                            (errors.role && touched.role ? " is-invalid" : "")
                        }
                        classNamePrefix="react-select"
                        value={values.role}
                        onChange={selectedOptions => {
                            // Setting field value - name of the field and values chosen.
                            setFieldValue("role", selectedOptions)}
                            }
                        onBlur={setFieldTouched}
                        options={options}
                        />
                        {errors.role && touched.role && 
                        <ErrorMessage
                        name="role"
                        component="div"
                        className="invalid-feedback d-block"
                        />}
                      </div>


                      <div className="form-group">
                        <div className="checkbox-wrapper">
                            <Field
                              name="consent"
                              type="checkbox"
                              checked={values.consent}
                              className={
                                "checkbox" +
                                (errors.consent && touched.consent ? " is-invalid" : "")
                              }
                            />
                        <label htmlFor="consent" className="checkbox_label_wrapper">
                          You must accept the{" "}
                          <Link className="links" to={"/Terms"}>
                            Terms of Use
                          </Link>{" "}
                          and{" "}
                          <Link className="links" to={"/Privacy"}>
                            Privacy Policy
                          </Link>


                        </label>
                        </div>

                        {errors.consent && touched.consent && 
                        <ErrorMessage
                          name="consent"
                          component="div"
                          className="invalid-feedback d-block"
                        />
                        }
                      </div>


                      <div className="form-group">
                        <Button
                          variant="outline-primary"
                          type="submit"
                          style={style3}
                          id="submitRegistration"
                          onClick={handleSubmit}
                          disabled={!dirty || isSubmitting}

                          >
                          Register
                        </Button>
                      </div>
                    </Form>
                    <Demo />
                    <Footer />
                    </div>


                  );
                }
                } 
            /> 
        )    

    }
}            

export default PreregForm;
```

**Next attempt**

When I try Julius solution, the alert appears, but as a footer beneath the form - not as a popup alert.

[image]

Comment: Don't worry everyone. I can't get the alert to work - but I have found a workaround. I can use a modal to give the alert instead. Thanks for trying to help. So weird how things that must be used by so many people don't work for me

Comment: I think your question was answered, just that you were using alert which gets displayed where it was inserted instead of popping up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use state and conditional rendering. Instead of returning a component set state to a variable, in your render use conditional rendering to check if the value is true.

```
handleSubmit = (formState, { resetForm }) => {
  // Now, you're getting form state here!
  const payload = {
    ...formState,
    role: formState.role.value,
    createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
  };
  console.log('formvalues', payload);

  fsDB
    .collection('register')
    .add(payload)
    .then(docRef => {
      resetForm(initialValues);
    })
    .then(e => this.setState({ alert: true }))

    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error adding document: ', error);
    });
};
```

In your render

```
render() {
 ...
  return(
 ....
   {this.state.alert && <AlertDismissible />}
 ...
  )
}
```

[Example Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qwj7xv)

Complete form

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage, withFormik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { fsDB, firebase, settings } from '../../firebase';
import Temporarynav from '../navigation/Temporarynav.jsx';
import Demo from '../landing/Demo.jsx';
import Footer from '../footer/Footer.jsx';
import './preregister/Form.css';
import AlertDismissible from '../auth/preregister/Alert';

import {
  Badge,
  Button,
  Col,
  ComponentClass,
  Feedback,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Table,
  Row,
  Container
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert';

const style1 = {
  width: '60%',
  margin: 'auto'
};

const style2 = {
  paddingTop: '2em'
};

const style3 = {
  marginRight: '2em'
};

const initialValues = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  email: '',
  role: '',
  consent: false,
  createdAt: ''
};

class PreregForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // the flag isFormDone will control where you will show the Alert component
    this.state = {
      showAlert: false
    };
  }
  handleSubmit = (formState, { resetForm }) => {
    // Now, you're getting form state here!
    const payload = {
      ...formState,
      role: formState.role.value,
      createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    };
    console.log('formvalues', payload);

    fsDB
      .collection('preregistrations')
      .add(payload)
      .then(docRef => {
        resetForm(initialValues);
      })
      .then(e => this.setState({ showAlert: true }))
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error adding document: ', error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    const options = [
      { value: 'academic', label: 'Academic Researcher' },
      { value: 'student', label: 'Student (inc PhD)' }
    ];

    // const {isFormDone} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {!this.state.showAlert ? (
          <div>
            <Formik
              initialValues={initialValues}
              validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
                firstName: Yup.string().required('First Name is required'),
                lastName: Yup.string().required('Last Name is required'),
                email: Yup.string()
                  .email('Email is invalid')
                  .required('Email is required'),
                role: Yup.string()
                  .nullable()
                  .required(
                    'It will help us get started if we know a little about your background'
                  ),
                consent: Yup.boolean().oneOf(
                  [true],
                  'You must accept the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy'
                )
              })}
              onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              render={({
                errors,
                status,
                touched,
                setFieldValue,
                setFieldTouched,
                handleSubmit,
                isSubmitting,
                dirty,
                values
              }) => {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <Temporarynav />
                    <Form style={style1}>
                      <h1 style={style2}>Get Started</h1>
                      <p>
                        We're almost ready to open this up to the research
                        community. By registering now, you'll be first in line
                        when the doors open.
                      </p>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                        <Field
                          name="firstName"
                          type="text"
                          className={
                            'form-control' +
                            (errors.firstName && touched.firstName
                              ? ' is-invalid'
                              : '')
                          }
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage
                          name="firstName"
                          component="div"
                          className="invalid-feedback"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                        <Field
                          name="lastName"
                          type="text"
                          className={
                            'form-control' +
                            (errors.lastName && touched.lastName
                              ? ' is-invalid'
                              : '')
                          }
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage
                          name="lastName"
                          component="div"
                          className="invalid-feedback"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                        <Field
                          name="email"
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="Please use your work email address"
                          className={
                            'form-control' +
                            (errors.email && touched.email ? ' is-invalid' : '')
                          }
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage
                          name="email"
                          component="div"
                          className="invalid-feedback"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="role">
                          Which role best describes yours?
                        </label>

                        <Select
                          key={`my_unique_select_keyrole`}
                          name="role"
                          className={
                            'react-select-container' +
                            (errors.role && touched.role ? ' is-invalid' : '')
                          }
                          classNamePrefix="react-select"
                          value={values.role}
                          onChange={selectedOptions => {
                            // Setting field value - name of the field and values chosen.
                            setFieldValue('role', selectedOptions);
                          }}
                          onBlur={setFieldTouched}
                          options={options}
                        />
                        {errors.role && touched.role && (
                          <ErrorMessage
                            name="role"
                            component="div"
                            className="invalid-feedback d-block"
                          />
                        )}
                      </div>

                      <div className="form-group">
                        <div className="checkbox-wrapper">
                          <Field
                            name="consent"
                            type="checkbox"
                            checked={values.consent}
                            className={
                              'checkbox' +
                              (errors.consent && touched.consent
                                ? ' is-invalid'
                                : '')
                            }
                          />
                          <label
                            htmlFor="consent"
                            className="checkbox_label_wrapper"
                          >
                            You must accept the{' '}
                            <Link className="links" to={'/Terms'}>
                              Terms of Use
                            </Link>{' '}
                            and{' '}
                            <Link className="links" to={'/Privacy'}>
                              Privacy Policy
                            </Link>
                          </label>
                        </div>

                        {errors.consent && touched.consent && (
                          <ErrorMessage
                            name="consent"
                            component="div"
                            className="invalid-feedback d-block"
                          />
                        )}
                      </div>

                      <div className="form-group">
                        <Button
                          variant="outline-primary"
                          type="submit"
                          style={style3}
                          id="submitRegistration"
                          onClick={handleSubmit}
                          disabled={!dirty || isSubmitting}
                        >
                          Register
                        </Button>
                      </div>
                    </Form>
                    <Demo />
                    <Footer />
                  </div>
                );
              }}
            />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <AlertDismissible />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PreregForm;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193833/discussion-on-answer-by-junius-l-add-a-react-bootstrap-alert-to-handlesubmit-in).

Comment: I just tried this. Instead of popping up like an alert, it displays beneath the footer like and additional footer.

Comment: please share your code here https://codeshare.io/an7Erv, I've updated the form code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a component like that within the `then` function.
You should manage a state flag that shows the alert based on the form completion.

Maybe you could share your whole component where you are handling the `submit` shown here so we can give you more help (will update the answer if you update the question).

But I think it would be something along the following lines:

```js
class MyFormComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // the flag isFormDone will control where you will show the Alert component
    this.state = {
      isFormDone: false
    };
  }

  /** Here your form handling as you posted */
  handleSubmit = (formState, { resetForm }) => {
      const payload = {
          ...formState,
          role: formState.role.value,
          createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        }
        console.log("formvalues", payload);

      fsDB
        .collection("register")
        .add(payload)
        .then(docRef => {
          resetForm(initialValues);

        })
        .then(() => {
          // Here is where you flag your form completion and allow the alert to be shown.
          this.setState((prevState) => ({...prevState, isFormDone: true}));
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
  }


  render() {

    const {isFormDone} = this.state;

    // this will only render the Alert when you complete your form submission
    const alert = isFormDone ? <AlertDismissible/> : null;

    return(
      {/* syntax sugar for React Fragment */}
      <> 
        {/* if it is null, it won't render anything */}
        {alert}

        {/* Your Form here with your handler */}
        {/* ... */}
      </>
      );

  }

}
```

Comment: it's Formik - so doesn't really need a state change in the form fields, but I updated my post to include my submit button

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is Formik or not. I also use Formik. You are not handling state form, but state for the wrapper component around the form.
That way you can control when showing the Alert component without touching the form.
Does that make sense?

Comment: The error message points to the then statement and says:   Line 81:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

Comment: Can you post the entire file? Because line 81 doesn't help with the current question structure. Can you post a jsfiddle.net with your code so we can try?

Comment: i deleted the line and added the whole form

Comment: You `catch` function is inside the `then` function just after commenting out the line I suggested. It should be  after the `then` call.

Comment: I also updated my answer. there was a pair of `(` missing.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I meant there was a syntax mistake on your updated question and also on my answer. My answer is up2date now and should fit your needs.

Comment: I just tried this. the same problem as previously reported occurs. Instead of popping up like an alert, this gets added to the bottom of the page like a footer

Comment: Are you sure you want an `Alert`? Don't you want a `Modal` instead? That take up the entire screen?
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modals-live

Comment: i really only need an alert, but i can't get it working. the modal is fine and it does the job

Comment: Then you just need to render the `alert` before your form. I updated my answer.